# Find the Fourier Transformed of $ f(t) = -2e^{-3|t+3|} + e^{j4t}\cdot\frac{1}{1+t^2} $

Tags: fourier-transform

Currently I try to find the Fourier transformed of this function: 
$ f(t) = -2e^{-3|t+3|} + e^{j4t}\cdot\frac{1}{1+t^2} $

I tried the following:
$$ \mathcal{F}\{f(t)\} = -2\cdot \mathcal{F} \{e^{-3|t+3|}\} + \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{e^{j4t}}{1+t^2}\} $$ 
My approach for $ \mathcal{F} \{e^{-3|t+3|}\} $ was to split the absolute function.

$$ e^{-3|t+3|} = e^{-3t-9} = e^{-3t}\cdot e^{-9}, t \ge -3 $$
$$ e^{-3|t+3|} = e^{3t+9} = e^{3t}\cdot e^{9}, t \le -3 $$

For the first one:
$$ \mathcal{F} \{e^{-3t-9}\} = \mathcal{F}\{e^{-3t}\cdot e^{-9}\} = e^{-9} \cdot \mathcal{F} \{e^{-3t}\} = e^{-9} \cdot \frac{6}{9 + \omega^2} $$

The second one could be: 
$$ \mathcal{F} \{e^{3t+9}\} = \mathcal{F}\{e^{3t}\cdot e^{9}\} = e^{9} \cdot \mathcal{F} \{e^{3t}\} $$

I can't tell if the first one is correct and if my approach to split up the absolute function was the right way. Also I'm completely failing with $ \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{e^{j4t}}{1+t^2}\} $
Could someone give me some advise?

Comment: For the first one you seem to have a typo.  The second case, you need $t\le -3$  For the second term you need to get the transform of $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ and shift the argument by $4$.

Comment: First evaluate $\mathcal F[e^{-|t|}]$ by reducing it to $\int_0^\infty e^{-t} e^{i \omega t} dt$. You'll find out that you do not have to compute $\mathcal F[1/(t^2+1)]$.

Comment: @Maxim I don't get the approach for the second Fourier term. It's $ \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{e^{j4t}}{1+t^2}\} $ and you only wrote $ \mathcal F[1/(t^2+1)] $ what to do with $ e^{j4t} $?

Comment: FT of $\frac {e^{j4t}} {1+t^{2}}$ at the point $x$ is nothing but FT of $\frac 1 {1+t^{2}}$ at $x-4$.

Comment: Did I understand it correctly that the approach would be to move the function 4 units. $ f(x-4) = \frac{e^{j4\cdot (x-4)}}{1+(x-4)^2} $. When I expand this I get $ \frac{e^{-j16} \cdot e^{j4x}}{1+(x-4)^2} $. Which doesn't help very much. I'm feeling that I'm missing something pretty simple but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $e^{-a|t|}$ and $\frac {2a}{a^2+w^2}$ are a Fourier transform pair. In the following all integrals are $-\infty,\infty$.

$\int e^{-3|t+3|}e^{-itw}dt=\int e^{-3|u|}e^{-i(u-3)w}du+\frac{6e^{3iw}}{9+w^2}$.  Here $u=t+3$ and the direct transform was used.

For the second term, $\int \frac{e^{4it}}{1+t^2}e^{-itw}dt=\int \frac{e^{is(w-4)}}{1+s^2}ds=\pi e^{-|w-4|}$. Here $s=-t$ and the inverse transform was used.

Net result: transform=$\frac{-12e^{3iw}}{9+w^2}+\pi e^{-|w-4|}$

Comment: What do you mean with "the inverse transform was used"?

Comment: @TimSch To get from $\frac{2a}{a^2+t^2}$ I used the fact that it was the transform of $e^{-a|w|}$ as noted in the answer (switching $w$ and $t$).  The inverse transform formula has a coefficient of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ 
  
  
 .http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/11ODU/FourierTransformPairs.pdf